# Ways to see if data has changed in a particular column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table and want to know the best way to see if there had been any data changes to one particular column, and if so, I would want to get an email alert - if that is possible.

My idea is to create a base table that only has this column with the data, lets say its called `'mytable'`. The column is 'Reporting_code'

Then every day I would do a `select distinct` for this column in the main table. If the value is new or changed it would display it.

```
Select distinct reporting_code a from Prod_table where reporting_code a not in 
(select distinct reporting_code b from mytable)
```

But is there a better way to be doing this?

Comment: CDC/trigger/column with old value to compare/timestamp/shadow table. There are many possible solutions.

Comment: You shouldn't need to make `mytable` contain all the values if all you care about is distinct values. Couldn't you just create `mytable` from the distinct values, thus potentially significantly reducing the size of `mytable` and the complexity of querying it? Your idea would probably work if you only cared about the distinct set of values changing, but not if a value was changed to another already-existing value. Is this not a concern?

Comment: They would never modify a value, they might delete, Mostly they would add new values.

Comment: The only time I like triggers is this scenario.  My suggestion is to make an archive table that is populated by a delete trigger on the main table.  Then add a created date column/constraint to the main table.  You can set up a daily report to monitor the changes quite easily with that setup.